# Prepend every element of a list in ansible

Tags: filter, ansible, jinja2

I am looking to prepend a list of users with the netbios domain name and backslash. So far this is the best I can come up with:

```
- hosts: servers 
   vars:
    mylist: 
     - Alice
     - Bob 
     - Carol
    mystring: test
    mylist2: "{{ mylist | map('regex_replace', '^', mystring + '\' ) | list }}" 
  tasks:
   - debug: var=mylist2
```

Error message below:

```
The offending line appears to be:

mystring: test
mylist2: "{{ mylist | map('regex_replace', '^', mystring + '\' ) | list }}"
                                                            ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

with_items:
  - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

I am facing an issue with concatenating a backslash to my variable because ansible thinks I am trying to escape something but haven't put what I want to escape. I have also tried to use a double backslash to no avail.

Can someone suggest what might work here or an alternative approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the expression and put the regex_replace parameters into variables, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    mylist: 
     - Alice
     - Bob 
     - Carol
    mystring: test
    mylist2: "{{ mylist|map('regex_replace', _my_regex, _my_replace)|list }}"
    _my_regex: '^(.*)$'
    _my_replace: '{{ mystring ~ "\\" ~ "\1" }}'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: mylist2
```

gives probably what you want

```yaml
  mylist2:
  - test\Alice
  - test\Bob
  - test\Carol
```